# Insert image a jpg file into a PDF document using Java pdfbox only 1/4 of image show up in the PDF document

Tags: java, java-8, jpeg, pdfbox

I am trying to insert a jpg file 1680 in width and 1080 in height into a PDF document using Java PDFBox library. I am trying to insert the image at 20,20 of the document and only 1/4 of image show up in the PDF.  I need to insert multiple images and each image into a separate page. Here is my code, please tell me what I did wrong ?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject;

public class pdfAddingPages {

public static void main(String[] args) {
     //Creating PDF document object 
      PDDocument document = new PDDocument();


         PDPage Page1 = new PDPage();

         //Adding the blank page to the document
         document.addPage( Page1 );


    //Creating PDImageXObject object
    PDImageXObject pdImage = null;
    try {
        pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromFile("C:/Test/image1680x1080.jpeg",document);
    } catch (IOException e4) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e4.printStackTrace();
    }

      //creating the PDPageContentStream object
      PDPageContentStream contents;
    try {
        contents = new PDPageContentStream(document, Page1);
        contents.drawImage(pdImage, 20, 20);  // positon at 20,20
        //contents.drawImage(pdImage, 0, 0, 1638, 1080);

        contents.close();
        //int chartWidth = 1638;  //2000, 1900, 1800
            //int chartHeight = 1080 ;

    } catch (IOException e3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e3.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Saving the document
    try {
        document.save("C:/Test/my_doc_image.pdf");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      System.out.println("PDF created");

      //Closing the document
      try {
        document.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to draw the image at a smaller size, use a scale factor:

```
contents.drawImage(pdImage, 20, 20, pdImage.getWidth() / 4, pdImage.getHeight() / 4);
```

Comment: It works but the image show up in the lower left hand corner and there is blank space on the top of the page. Do you know why ? I try change to   contents.drawImage(pdImage, 0, 0, pdImage.getWidth() / 4, pdImage.getHeight() / 4);  It didn't make any different.

Comment: I accept your solution. By scale alone doesn't work well. I have to change to landscape mode by insert the following code. ----------------------float POINTS_PER_INCH = 72;
float POINTS_PER_MM = 1 / (10 * 2.54f) * POINTS_PER_INCH; 
PDPage page = new PDPage(new PDRectangle(400 * POINTS_PER_MM, 210 * POINTS_PER_MM));